# How to redirect urls on a NGINX environment?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, nginx

I am trying to redirect from:
http://domain.com/public/photos/large/test.jpg 
to:
http://domain.com/images/public/photos/large/test.jpg
on a NGINX environment.

My vhost file is configured like the next lines.
My problem is that a syntax like this is not working:

```
server {
       ........
       rewrite ^(public/photos/(.*)) http://domain.com/images/$1 last;
       location / {
            location ~.*\.(3gp|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
                expires 7d;
                try_files $uri @backend;
            } 
       }
       ..........
}
```

The rewriterule syntax was tested on a .htaccess environment and it worked for more than 2 years now. On nginx it doesn't anymore.

Any ideas?
10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/public/photos/(.*)$ http://domain.com/images/public/photos/$1 last;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. No luck yet. I modified it, and then restarted NGINX, and http service.